# django custom form validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In Django/Python, when you make a custom form, does it need to have a clean() method, or will calling .is_valid() perform a default validation?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        filter = FilterForm(request.POST)
        if filter.is_valid():
            print 'Month is ' + filter.cleaned_data['month']
            print 'Type is ' + filter.cleaned_data['type']
            print 'Number is ' +filter.cleaned_data['number']
        else:
            print 'Invalid form'
            print filter.errors
```

"Invalid Form" gets printed but no errors get printed.

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    months = [('January','January'),
                  ('February','February'),
                  ('March','March'),
                  ('April','April'),
                  ('May','May'),
                  ('June','June'),
                  ('July','July'),
                  ('August','August'),
                  ('September','September'),
                  ('October','October'),
                  ('November','November'),
                  ('December','December'),]
    types = [('text','Text'),
                 ('call','Call'),] 

    month = forms.ChoiceField(months)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=types,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self,numbers,*args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['number'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=numbers)

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

I've tried it with and without the clean method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it need to have a clean() method

No. Completely optional.

There's a big list of things that Django does in a specific order when it validates forms. You can learn about the process here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

As for finding your problem, if you stick a `{{form.errors}}` on your template, you'll see which field is blowing up. I have a feeling it could be that your choices is defined in a place that something can't get a handle on when it needs to (Move them out of the class).

Edit: Almost missed this. Look at this line:

```
def __init__(self,numbers,*args, **kwargs)
```

And then look at this line:

```
filter = FilterForm(request.POST)
```

You need to pass the `numbers` argument in this time too. It's a completely new instance. it can't validate because it doesn't know what `numbers` is.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary.  I'd read that page.  Someone here seems to be having the same problem: http://thedjangoforum.com/board/thread/584/form-is-valid-always-returns-false/  When I print the field errors I just get an empty line so I'm not sure how to figure out what's wrong

Comment: It wouldn't let me do this filter = FilterForm(numbers=[],request.POST) or this filter = FilterForm(request.POST,numbers=[])

Comment: How about just `FilterForm([],request.POST)`?mixing args and kwargs can get messy.

Answer (score 3):

If you have no specific `clean` method, Django will still validate all the fields in your form to ensure that all required fields are present, that they have the correct type where necessary, and that fields with choices have a value corresponding to one of the choices.

There are a couple of issues with this form that could be causing your problem. Firstly, you have overridden `__init__` so that the first parameter after `self` is `numbers`. However, when you instantiate the form you don't pass this parameter - you just pass `request.POST`.

Secondly, it's a bad idea to add fields dynamically to `self.fields` as you do in `__init__`. Instead, declare your `number` field with an empty `choices` list and just set that in `__init__`:

```
self.fields['number'].choices = numbers
```

Comment: I fixed the second suggestion, thanks.  I'm not sure how to deal with the first one though.  When I'm posting, I say filter = FilterForm(request.POST).  I thought that's how forms are supposed to work. I also need to be able to pass in a list of choices to display even if I'm not posting so I say filter = FilterForm(thelist).